# How to create html structure which will allow only 3 div elements in each li. In React + underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, underscore.js

For creating this structure i want to use only underscore.js methods.
I have below array .

```
 var xyz = [{
    'name': 'test'
 },{
    'name': 'test1'
 },{        
    'name': 'test2'
 },{ 
    'name': 'test3'
 },{ 
    'name': 'test4'
 },{
    'name': 'test5'
```

}];

And HTML structure should create like this -

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <div><span>test3</span></div>
       <div><span>test4</span></div>
       <div><span>test5</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
       <div><span>test6</span></div>
       <div><span>test7</span></div>
       <div><span>test8</span></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am using React and underscore.js on my project.

Comment: Do you want to render this HTML with React components ?

Comment: @Pcriulan : Yes I want this with react.js
But from few people i got to know that this is bad practice to have html as string  in react.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of a pure React function (it could also be a component), you could do something like the following:

```
    <span>
        {_.map(_.chunk(xyz, 3), (innerItem, i) => (
            <ul key={i}>
                {_.map(innerItem, ({name}, j) => (<li key={j}>{name}</li>))}
            </ul>
        ))}
    </span>
```

Comment: @Chirs Its giving error at below line -
    
     _.map(innerItem, {name} => (<li>{name}</li>))

Comment: Its hard to tell without the error message, but I have updated the answer to be a bit more broad. Also see this bin: http://jsbin.com/menidu/3/edit?js,output

Comment: Can i make Source array to
var xyz = {"name": ["hi",hello","wer","test"]};

Comment: Yes, but would require a restructure of the above code and a new question/answer on stackoverflow (imo)

Comment: : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057727/create-html-structure-which-will-allow-only-3-div-elements-in-each-li-in-react
please check the link. I have created new question. Sorry but i m not able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var xyz = [{'name':'test'},{'name':'test1'},{'name':'test2'},{'name':'test3'},{'name':'test4'},{'name':'test5'}];

  var htmlStr = "<ul><li>";
  var cnt = 0;
  $(xyz).each(function(i,v) {
    if(cnt != 0 && cnt % 3 == 0) {
      htmlStr += "</li><li>";
    }
    htmlStr += "<div><span>"+v.name+"</span></div>";
    cnt++;
  });
  htmlStr += "</li></ul>";
  $("#test").html(htmlStr)
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the array into chunks and use underscore _.template method for creating html:

```
var xyz = [{
'name': 'test'
},{
    'name': 'test1'
},{        
    'name': 'test2'
},{ 
    'name': 'test3'
},{ 
    'name': 'test4'
},{
    'name': 'test5'
}];

var chunkedXyz = _.chain(xyz).groupBy(function(element, index){
  return Math.floor(index/3);
}).toArray().value();

var liTemplate = _.template("<% _.each(liElements, function(liContent) { %> <div><span><%= liContent.name %></span></div> <% }); %>");
var ulTemplate = _.template("<% _.each(chunkedXyz, function(liItem) { %> <li><%= liTemplate({liElements: liItem}) %></li> <% }); %>");

var layout = "<ul>" + ulTemplate({
    chunkedXyz: chunkedXyz,
    liTemplate: liTemplate
}) + "</ul>";

console.log(layout.toString());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1m5ayhzw/

Comment: Guys I have one question ? I am ok wth this code but is it good practice to pass html as string in React.js. I have find dangerouslySetInnerHTML in react . but few are saying  it is not good practice to do this in react.

Comment: No, for React-JSX syntax, to do as explained in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38012928/5806646 I do not noticed that you are using React

Comment: It is core js version of it. I added it in react , I have used                                <ul dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} /> this code format .But my PR get rejected  :)

Comment: Can you please check my question once again.
There are few changes in array.I have tried that with react.js but facing few problems.